# How can i include folders from other repos when running a pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have a repo called REPO A and have created a YAML pipeline in here but I also have some code in REPO B which I need to use in this pipeline

In YAML how can tell the pipeline in REPO A to use files/folders from REPO B?

Im a newbie to this so can you please keep it simple?

```
    resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: automation
      type: git
      name: MYORG/ automation
      ref: develop
      endpoint: YourEndpoint

  steps:
    - checkout: self
      path: "s/Source" :  ***>>>>>> what should this be??***
    - checkout: automation
```

Answer (score 2):

ok simply put at the top of the yaml i added

```
> resources:

    >       repositories:
    >       - repository: automation
    >         type: git
    >         name: name of yourpoject/name of repo you want to use 
    >         ref: whatever branch of that repo(under repository above) you want to use
```

THEN!! under steps in the YAML (if you havent one you need to add it!)

```
>    steps:
>         - checkout: self 
>         - checkout: your repository you want to use as above
```

Also if you use npm to run a task you need to add the below as well to not get any file not found errors! a common error if you dont add the below code is : **npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/work/package.json**

The below code is put in the -Task section

```
>     >    npm install
>     >       displayName: 'a task using npm'
>     >       workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/your repository you  want to use as above
```

ALSO be aware of indentation when inserting code in YAML it's annoying and a pain if you havent got the indentation right it gives you errors just tab until they go away

Answer (score 0):

You should check out multiple repositories on your YAML pipeline. You can define a new resource repository and checkout this repository along with your source (the one that triggers the pipeline).

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops_sf
      type: github
      name: Organization/Repository
      ref: master
      endpoint: YourEndpoint

  steps:
    - checkout: self
      path: "s/Source"
    - checkout: devops_sf
```

Then you will be able to access your repositories under

```
$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/Repository
$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/Source
```

Multi repo checkout for Azure DevOps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops

Comment: I did try that but am not sure where im supposed to get the endpoint from? I log in with a user name and password  into Azure Devops so am unclear what value this should be. Also is the repository under the name field the same as repository under the repository field?

Comment: Your endpoint should be a service connection with your Github organization/account. This can be accomplished under Project settings -> Github connections. If you use Azure Devops repositories you should change the provided code and use `type:git` and follow the instruction from the provided link. Yes it the same repository, you just provide a friendly name for your DevOps pipeline in order to checkout

Comment: ok i get this error when using the above code : 
Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/pipelines/vtest-pipelines.yml (Line: 10, Col: 3): Unexpected value 'repositories'

Comment: resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: automation
      type: git
      name: myorg/automation
      ref: develop
      endpoint: YourEndpoint

  steps:
    - checkout: self
      path: "s/Source"
    - checkout: automation

Comment: @itye1970 paste your code in the question section so that we can have a view.

Comment: ok have pasted the code in, as im very new to this apologies for the questions

Comment: you must correct the identation of the YAML file (look my example YAML file) resources should be on the left side of repositories. s/Source should be the location on which you want to checkout your source repository code.

Comment: ill try that and update the thread

Comment: /pipelines/testazure-pipelines.yml (Line: 26, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'stages , i get this error now?

Comment: i still cant get this working , its very confusing, all i need to do is include folders from another repo , its all very confusing

Comment: i worked it out myself